# What is the meaning of the existence of a large $N$ limit in QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, approximations, large-n

[Large $N$ limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/N_expansion) are present in many different contexts: matrix models, gauge theories in various dimensions, conformal field theories (where $N$ is essentially the central charge).

We often hear things like "we assume that the large $N$ limit exists" (assuming maybe some scaling of the coupling constant for instance).

What does this mean precisely?

Do we mean that the large $N$ limit of any correlation function is finite?

If yes, should these correlation functions satisfy the axioms of QFT, or could they violate some of them (even if at finite $N$ there's no such violation)?